# How can I add a document class to Texmaker on Mac?

Tags: document-classes, texmaker, mactex

I am about to write my thesis on Texmaker but frankly I am a quite clueless tex-virgin.

I would like to use the document class of our university but I couldn't figure out how I can import the files to Texmaker. Does anyone know how to do this?

FYI: There is a bitex, a src, a lyx and a src folder with files included. I tried adding them manually to a library folder called texfm but the new class didn't show up in texmaker.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you add a listing of the files with the folders they're in? Placing them suitably is not difficult, but one has to know the file types.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Open a Finder window; then press Command-Shift-G and in the box type

```
~/Library
```

In the window that opens, create a folder named

```
texmf
```

Open this folder and create inside it

```
tex
```

Inside this one create

```
latex
```

and again inside this create

```
myuniversityclass
```

The final path is

```
~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/myuniversityclass
```

The last name is arbitrary, choose whatever you want (no spaces, ever). In this last folder place the class file provided by your university (something like `universityname.cls`). Then TeX programs will find it.

For the BibTeX file (something like `universityname.bst`) you have to create a slightly different path:

```
~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst/myuniversitybst
```

and place the `.bst` file in the last folder.

Other files might require a different place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
I copied the files in the their specific locations. However, when I use the assistant for creating a new document in texmaker, the university-styles do not appear. Is this normal? Or how can I use them if they don't appear in the assistant?

Answer (score 1):

TeXmaker can’t scan all folders to find (custom) document classes. It has a few preadded by the developers for the assistant. Further classes can be added by the user in the assistants window, by clicking the first plus button.

[image: add a class]

---

### some clarifications :-)

TeXmaker is only an editor exactly as Notepad, TextEdit, vi or what ever. It was designed to be used for TeX “programming” but has nothing to do with TeX per se. It just knows how to process a TeX document and starts this process in background when you click build. Thats the reason that you don’t have to (and can’t) add a class to TeXmaker. Instead you must add a class to your Distribution (e.g. MacTeX, TeX Live, MikTeX). The distribution is the whole bunch of files and (terminal based) applications to typeset a TeX file. Usually the distribution is synced with [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org), by using `tlmgr` (with or without a GUI, e.g. TeX Live Utility for MacTeX). If a user wants to add a file, like a class in your case, he should do that in the user `texmf` folder (see egregs answer), otherwise it would be deleted when syncing with CTAN. egreg showed how to add a file to the distribution in his answer.

Now back to TeXmaker, since it is just a text editor it can’t know which classes are available on your system. The developers assumed a minimum set of default classes and added them to the assistant. But that neither means that all classes from the assistant are available in your distribution (but its ver likely) nor that you can only use classes available in the assistant. Furthermore the assistant give me the same template code for a predefined class and for the classes manually added by myself …

In general you tell TeX which class to use with

```
\documentclass{classname}
```

at the begin of you file. To change the class replace `classname` by the name of another class.

I always recommend not to use such assistants or templates, espeacially as a TeX beginner, because they include a lot line of code you don’t understand and that will cause problems sooner or later. It is better to read a beginners guide and built up the document from scratch, then you’ll know what each line does, and changing the document class will be a cake walk `;-)`

Comment: Hi,

by adding a new class I can only define a new profile myself. But I would like to use the pre-defined profile. After adding the files to the right directory, can I maybe select the right document class in the code instead of the assistant?

E.g. like in the document header but exchanging the document class by something else (but what?): http://i.imgur.com/PP9si5v.png

Comment: Sure, you can change the document class bay changing the argument of `\documentclass`, which is `book` in your image.