# How to add new packages to Texmaker?

Tags: texmaker

How can I add a package, e.g., `program` into Texmaker in Ubuntu?
I tried to include it as follows but it didn't work:

```
\usepackage{program}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same ID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Do you mean autocomplete in TeXmaker for loading `\usepackage{program}`  ? Note: TeXmaker is just an IDE/LaTeX editor to type the source and then send to `pdflatex` engine.

Comment: `\usepackage{}` should work...make sure you have installed the required packages correctly...if you want you can check out these [solutions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10316/how-to-install-new-packages-on-texmaker-on-ubuntu) on how to install new packages on Texmaker on Ubuntu...hope it helps...:)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124967/4918. Please read the “clarifications” in my answer …

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` for all packages in Ubuntus repositories (asuming you have not done this).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you haven't done it, the command `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` in terminal gives you all the packages in the Ubuntu repositories, which should give you the package you seek.

It is a pretty large chunk of files, so be sure to have enough space. The drawback with this method is of course that you get a lot of packages you might never use, and documentation. To prevent this a search for `texlive` in Synaptic gives you the possibility to install the bundles you want. The description of the package states which tex-packages that comes with it.

Another possibility is to install "vanilla" TeX. It is described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu). This gives you better package managing.