# Texmaker, documentclass imsart not found

Tags: packages, texmaker

I am running a mac machine and would like to write a paper using the imsart documentclass. I downloaded the imsart file (http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/ims-instructions.html) and put the entire folder in the same folder where my other latex styles (e.g. ams math etc.) are located. However, running texmaker I get the following:

> LOG FILE : This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live
>   2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.12.19) 19 DEC 2017 18:06
>   entering extended mode restricted \write18 enabled. %&-line parsing
>   enabled.
>   **ArticleSinkhorn.tex (./ArticleSinkhorn.tex LaTeX2e <2017-04-15> Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded. !
>   LaTeX Error: File `imsart.cls' not found. Type X to quit or 
>   to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: cls) Enter file
>   name: ! Emergency stop.  l.3 ^^M
>   *** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes) Here is how much of TeX's memory you used: 10 strings out of 492995 212 string characters
>   out of 6132703 54074 words of memory out of 5000000 3661 multiletter
>   control sequences out of 15000+600000 3640 words of font info for 14
>   fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>   10i,0n,7p,49b,8s stack positions out of
>   5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output
>   PDF file produced!

It seems that texmaker cannot find the 'imsart.cls'. I am more or less a brute force user and hope that this is enough information to help me :-)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you run `texhash` or for MikTeX updated the FNDB (file name data base)??

Comment: no. if you recommend me to do so, please let me know what to do :-)

Comment: open a terminal or for windows a command window and type `texhash <enter>`. That's all

Comment: Ok, I did it. It actually says the following:usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.
Texmaker still has the same problem. Doesn't find 'imsart.cls' :-(

Comment: I am no Mac user, but you may need to run this as administrator/root (which would explain the error message you get with `texhash`).

Comment: If I understand you correctly this is what happens after enabling root user: dsenableroot:: ***Successfully enabled root user.
Marcels-MBP-3:~ Cello$ texhash
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-config: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local: directory not writable. Skipping...
texhash: Done.

Comment: It seems that I finally solved it following this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124967/how-can-i-add-a-document-class-to-texmaker-on-mac :-)

Comment: Run `sudo texhash` and give your admin password when requested. PS: where, exactly did you put those files?